# GSA Database Feed Selective Recrawl Immediate

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have a database feed to GSA.
My systems have some events that I know will alter the value of some records.
I'd like to initiate immediate re-crawl in GSA for those selected records, via API or command line tools.

Is that possible?

Regards,
Kelvin Yeo

Answer (score 1):

1. GSA API, under "Freshness Tuning" - http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/acapi_java/acapi_java.html#1073256
2. GSA Admin toolkit - https://github.com/google/gsa-admin-toolkit

For myself, I prefer to add to GSA - "Content Sources" -> "Web Crawl" -> "Freshness Tuning" -> "Crawl Frequently" box.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tips. I actually want to re-crawl only certain records from a database connector (not entire connector as it will incur too much time). Can Freshness Tuning be that precise for database connectors?

Comment: I don't use database connectors. I have a page that pulls the latest from database and GSA crawls the links in the page.

Comment: From my researches so far, it seems that we can push a crawl to be very frequent and even immediate via Freshness Tuning, but adding to index is still not controllable and is not immediate. Closing this issue here then.